# GCP Connection Failed - SSH - We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, ufw

Since I received a email warning letter from google says "Action required: Critical problem with My First Project" saying my server has some abnormal outgoing activity , I tried to implemented ufw in my debian server.

For my ufw setting, I've done the following:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming 
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
```

After I restart my server , I can't connect to my server with the error "Connection Failed: We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue."

I followed the following instruction https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh but it still not working:

1. I tried gcloud to create default-allow-ssh 
   [my firewall-rules list picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxEcw.png)
2. I tried to use serial console to login but I haven't set password to my root account so I can't login.
3. I tried to add "/usr/sbin/ufw disable" to startup-script in Custom metadata and restart server many times but it seems the command is not executed so still not working
   [my gcp startup-script picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE9ip.png)

Comment: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Comment: Which OS and version?

Comment: My server is Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u5 (2019-08-11) x86_64
I tried adding the following to Custom metadata but it does not work
#! /bin/bash
/usr/sbin/ufw disable
and also
#! /bin/bash
/usr/sbin/ufw allow ssh

Comment: Then you will need to follow the second method in my article.

Comment: method 2 works! It's complicated but finally get it done. Thanks!

Comment: if you figured it out, could you add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct answer in this website. 
https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Method 2 in the website solves this problem